# jquery on click checkbox issue

Tags: jquery, html, alert

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/DBPjP/3/).

So I've set up this little example  of what I am trying to do. I want this checkbox to work as the following. When user tries to enable/click the checkbox (mostly for people who are not computer savvy), I would like for it to alert them saying "You must login to do this action".

I can't figure it out. I've been searching all over for an answer, and couldn't find one.

Thanks a lot in advance for all your answers!

Comment: It's not working because onclick events don't fire for disabled checkboxes.

Comment: Why is the checkbox disabled?

Comment: Here is a post very similar to yours.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781467/how-can-i-execute-a-function-when-a-disabled-checkbox-is-clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the `disabled` attribute from the checkbox. Also, if you want to show the alert only when the checkbox gets checked, use the following instead:

```
$(".check").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert("You must sign in to do this.");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Mitchell: Hi, what are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for it to alert me when disabled. but its fine. no worries. for my app its not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the checked and disabled attributes and use this code:

```
$(".check").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) alert("You must sign in to do this.");
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DBPjP/4/)**